# Whats wrong with this file upload?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I cant upload video files using this code for a form:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post"
enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and this is upload.php:

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000000)
  {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

    if (file_exists("videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
    }
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Please clarify *"cant"*. Any errors? Have you tried any debugging?

Comment: Also, do you have root access to server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your question is not clear but you can check the following things:

1) Can PHP write to the tempdirectory?

This is where PHP stores the file when it receives it. It will be destroyed
when the script end, so it is your scripts responsibility to MOVE IT OUT
before it ends.

2) Can PHP write to the targetdirectory?

Are you sure PHP has rights to write in the targetdirectory?

also check [php.ini](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.php) . Specially, check `php_value upload_max_filesize 20M`whether it is meet your uploaded file size or not.

Answer (score 2):

*On second thought*, I think a better solution would be to have two copies of PHP installed on the system. One solely to handle these uploads. This way, you can set these absurd php.ini values without adversely affecting the primary server. You probably won't need a second web server to do this, I think there would be a way to pass these arguments to the secondary php installation by running as CLI.

This is probably too complicated for your needs, but it may help someone else. Also, I'd like to see some feedback on this approach.

---

You will need to change these parameters in php.ini

```
post_max_size = 2100M
upload_max_filesize = 2100M
file_uploads = 1
memory_limit = 2200M
```

Keep in mind that increasing these limits can result in memory leaks crashing your server and making your server vulnerable to plenty of exploits.

Comment: this is the most common problem with PHP uploads.

Comment: Dont forget to also increase the max post size in your webserver configuration (e.g. Apache, IIS).